# How can my code only accept integers in Python?

Tags: python, error-handling

My code distinguishes whether the input is valid or not. It's not supposed to accept zero or words. If the user plugs zero in, it works and says "anything but zero", "try again" BUT when it asks again, it accepts anything. What do I do to make it continue to ask until there is a valid input??
So far I got:

```
A = raw_input('Enter A: ')
try:
    A = float(A)
    if A == 0:
        print "anything but zero"
        A = raw_input("Try again")
except ValueError:
    print "HEY! that is not a float!"
    A = raw_input("Try again")
```

Please help! Thank you all!

Comment: Did you try Googling your question's title?

Comment: I did! I've been trying but none worked.. That's where I got what I have already..

Comment: That dupe is actually terrible

Comment: The dupe question is terrible but the answer is good.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a loop:

```
while True:
    A = raw_input('Enter A:')
    try:
         A = float(A)
    except ValueError:
         print "enter a float!"
    else:
         if A == 0:
             print "Enter not 0"
         else:
             break
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is use a while loop and to move all the logic inside the try breaking if the cast is successful and not equal to 0:

```
while True:
    try:
        A = float(raw_input('Enter A: '))
        if A != 0:
            break
        print "anything but zero"
    except ValueError:
        print "HEY! that is not a float!"
```

If you actually only want integers you should be casting to `int` not `float`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop:

```
valid = false
while not valid:
    A = raw_input('Enter A: ')
    try:
        A = float(A)
        if A == 0:
            print "anything but zero"
            A = raw_input("Try again")
        else: 
            valid = true
    except ValueError:
        print "HEY! that is not a float!"
        A = raw_input("Try again")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps :)

```
while 1==1:
A = raw_input('Enter A: ')
try:
    A = float(A)
    if A == 0:
        print "anything but zero"
        A = raw_input("Try again")
    else:
        #valid input
        break
except ValueError:
    print "HEY! that is not a float!"
```